# HTTP2 Push- placing script tags in res.end

Tags: node.js, spdy, http2

After reading [HTTP2 Article using Speedy NPM module](https://www.igvita.com/2013/06/12/innovating-with-http-2.0-server-push/), I have a question.

The benefit of HTTP2 push is that the browser has the resources cached before the browser requests them.

In this example:

```
spdy.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
  // push JavaScript asset (/main.js) to the client
  res.push('/main.js', {'content-type': 'application/javascript'}, function(err, stream) {
    stream.end('alert("hello from push stream!")');
  });

  // write main response body and terminate stream
  res.end('Hello World! <script src="/main.js"></script>');
}).listen(443);
```

What does `<script src="/main.js"></script>` actually cause the browser to do in `res.end('Hello World! <script src="/main.js"></script>')`?

And if the index.html has `<script src="/main.js"></script>` inside of it, why place it in `res.end('Hello World! <script src="/main.js"></script>')`?

Comment: I am very interested in this as well. I was asked if I were adding the resource in the doc in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049872/http2-spdy-push-stream-verification-how-to-test#comment55854460_34049872).

Answer (score 1):

`res.end('Hello World! <script src="/main.js"></script>');` is sending a very minimal web page. (It is missing `<html><head><body> etc...`, because it's a bare-bones example.) It looks like this:

```
Hello World!
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

The web page displays "Hello World!" but you wouldn't see the `<script>` tag rendered. The browser parses the "web page", processes the link to `main.js` and discovers it already received that file (from the `.push`). Finally that script is executed and opens an `alert()`.

`main.js` was preemptively sent even before the "web page" content was delivered, that's the `res.push('/main.js',...)`.