# HTTP2 / SPDY Push-Stream Verification: How to Test?

Tags: node.js, spdy, http2, pushstream

**I am implementing HTTP2/SPDY push** resourcing using the node module [spdy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spdy). I have followed [indutny's doc](https://github.com/indutny/node-spdy#push-streams) and have been doing test runs implementing his example into my server.js.

**The problem is two fold;** I am not getting any errors in the log(s) nor am I seeing the `alert` in the browser. I don't see any change in the Developers Console as well. If I set a bogus push URL, I get no response/errors,etc. I believe in theory, the Priority should change from `medium` to `High`(?). [See Screen shoot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgNfk.png)

Is there another way for me to test if the push is being made to the browser? Or, do I have something wrong in my script (*Please check for inconsistencies*)? Also, what to throw in `stream.on('error', function() {});`?

Testing in Chrome (on a ChromeBook), nodejs v5.1.0, npm v3.3.12 - H2 enabled is verified in Chrome.

**server.js:**

```
var environment = '../env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV
    // Process User config
  , fS = require('fs')
  , jsonFile = fS.readFileSync(environment + '/config.json')
  , jsonString, hostIp, hostPort, cacheExp, cps;

    try {
      jsonString              = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
      var SERV_HOST           = jsonString['hostIp']
        , SERV_PORT           = jsonString['hostPort']
        , CACHE_EXP           = jsonString['cacheExp']
        , CPS                 = jsonString['cps']
        , xPowerBy            = 'OceanPress'
        , xFrameOptions       = 'DENY'
        , xXSSProtection      = '1; mode=block'
        , xContentTypeOption  = 'nosniff';
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('There is an error parsing the json file : ' + err);
    }

// Load modules
var fs          = require('fs')
  , watch       = require('staticsmith-watch')
  , buffet      = require('buffet')({root: environment + '/_public'})
  , spdy        = require('spdy')
    // spdy options
  , options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync(environment + '/keys/key.pem')
    , cert: fs.readFileSync(environment + '/keys/cert.pem')
    // SPDY-specific options
    , spdy: {
          protocols: [ 'h2','spdy/3.1', 'spdy/3', 'spdy/2','http/1.1', 'http/1.0' ]
        , plain: false
        , maxStreams: 200
        , connection: {
              windowSize: 1024 * 1024
            , autoSpdy31: false
          }
      }
      // Set ip and port
    , host:   SERV_HOST
    , port:   SERV_PORT
  }
    // Security header options
  , security  = [
      { name:   'X-Powered-By',
        option: xPowerBy }
    , { name:   'x-frame-options',
        option: xFrameOptions }
    , { name:   'X-XSS-Protection',
        option: xXSSProtection }
    , { name:   'X-Content-Type-Options',
        option: xContentTypeOption }
    , { name:   'Cache-Control',
        option: CACHE_EXP }
    , { name:   'Content-Security-Policy',
        option: CPS }
    , { name:   'server',
        option: 'Who knows' }
  ];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {

  spdy.createServer(options, function(req, res) {

    // Add Content Security Rules
    for(var i = 0; i < security.length; i++) {
      res.setHeader(security[i].name, security[i].option);
    }

    // @see https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffet
    buffet(req, res, function (err, result) {

      // Push JavaScript asset (main.js) to the client
      var stream = res.push('/js/main.js', {
        req: {'accept': '*/*'},
        res: {'content-type': 'application/javascript'}
      });
      stream.on('acknowledge', function() {
          console.log("Stream ACK");
      });
      stream.on('error', function() {
        console.error("stream ERR");
      });
      stream.end('alert("hello from push stream!");');
      // write main response body and terminate stream
      res.end('<script src="/js/main.js"></script>');

      // There was an error serving the file? Throw it!
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error serving " + req.url + " - " + err.message);
        // Respond to the client
        res.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
      }
    });
  }).listen(options.port, options.host);

  console.log("serving at https://" + options.host + ":" + options.port);
  console.log("On Node v" + process.versions.node);
  console.log("On npm v" + process.versions.npm);

  watch({
    pattern:    '**/*',
    livereload: true,
  });
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have also added:

```
  stream.on('acknowledge', function() {
      console.log('stream ACK');
  });
```

There is no console log written - It's like the function is dead.

**Dev Console with push-stream (main.js):**
[image: Dev Console with push-stream (main.js)]

Comment: In your index.html, do you have `<script src="main.js">`?  The browser will ignore pushed resources that it would otherwise have no reason to request.

Comment: Yes I do.  I tried running with out it in the doc and the app fails.

Comment: Is `stream` emitting an error?  At the minimum, you should log out error events.  Silently swallowing them is an excellent way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Yes I agree. Hence the question; I am unsure on testing or what to throw in   ```stream.on('error', function() {});``` Suggestions? Thnx.

Comment: I'd just throw `console.error(err)` in there so you can see if it is `stream` emitting an error.

Comment: Funny, it was there originally. I added it back in and retested - Throws nothing ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Within the Chrome inspector**, I discovered it is quite easily recognized when a resource has been pushed by the server.

**First:** Within the network view/tab, the resource(s) in question will show virtually no `request` sent and 'waiting(TTFB)' in the waterfall (*See image below*).

**The `theme.min.css` & `theme.min.js` resources are pushed:**

[image]

**Second:** After clicking on the pushed the resource(s), opening the "Headers" pane and inspecting the "Request Headers" panel at the bottom, check for `Provisional headers are shown`. If the warning is shown for the resource, then it was pushed. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34318995/742030) to why you will see this warning.

**Headers Inspector:**

[image]

If you need a little more detailed information about the pushed resource(s), using the `chrome://net-internals/#http2` method as stated in the second part of [@josh3736 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34051853/742030) would work too. But if you need a quick way to verify that the resource(s) has been pushed and excepted by the client, viewing the waterfall will show this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here.

1. The buffet callback is only invoked when the requested URL does **not** match a file on disk.  Just like express middleware, it's essentially a `next` function.  Thus, you're never actually pushing anything.
2. The first argument to `res.push` is a URL, not a filesystem path.
3. `res.push` will not exist on ≤ HTTP/1.1 connections; you need to make sure it's there or you'll throw an uncaught exception (and crash).

Here's a reduced working example.

```
spdy.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./s.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./s.crt')
}, function(req, res) {

    if (req.url == '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': 42 });
        res.end('<h1>Hi</h1><script src="main.js"></script>');

        if (res.push) {

            // Push JavaScript asset (main.js) to the client
            var stream = res.push('/main.js', {
                req: {'accept': '**/*'},
                res: {'content-type': 'application/javascript'}
            });

            stream.on('error', function() {
                console.error(err);
            });
            stream.end('alert("hello from push stream!");');
        }
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }



}).listen(777);
```

---

As far as actually verifying in Chrome that things are being pushed, open a new tab and type `chrome://net-internals/#http2`.  Click the ID of the HTTP/2 session with your server, then click the session in the left-hand pane.  Mixed in with the initial request, you'll see something like:

```
t=  3483 [st=    19]  HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_PUSH_PROMISE
                      --> :method: GET
                          :path: /main.js
                          :scheme: https
                          :authority: localhost:777
                      --> id = 3
                      --> promised_stream_id = 4
t=  3483 [st=    19]  HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_HEADERS
                      --> fin = false
                      --> :status: 200
                      --> stream_id = 4
t=  3483 [st=    19]  HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_DATA
                      --> fin = true
                      --> size = 0
                      --> stream_id = 4
t=  3546 [st=    82]  HTTP2_STREAM_ADOPTED_PUSH_STREAM
                      --> stream_id = 4
                      --> url = "https://localhost:777/main.js"
```

(I did not see the Priority of main.js change in the dev tools -- it was still Medium.)

Comment: Thnx 4 the input. 1. [Buffet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffet). 2. `res.push`:I read somewhere that id was CWD based.Ran your examp w/my dir setup & `res.end` is CWD and `res.push` is URL -THNX! 3. `res.push` will not exist on ≤ HTTP/1.1: I understood node-spdy took care of this (I'm prob wrong); I havent tested that far yet, just needing Push 2 work 1st. The issue I believe is that I am serving a static index file. [Does this matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511203/http2-push-placing-script-tags-in-res-end?rq=1) How would I inject the <script> - Or am I that far off? THNX

Comment: You need to push *before* handing the request off to buffet.  If buffet sees a request for a static file, your callback is never invoked.  Also make sure `req.url == '/'` (or whatever the URL of your main page is) -- you don't want to push the JS file along with every request for every single file on your sever.